# Unit test - relative path causing test to fail?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I have a `Java` unit test:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateCorectPerson() throws IOException, ParseException {

    //test data
    Person expectedPerson = createExpectedObject(PersonsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/my/package/personStub/person1Stub.json"));

    //other code and asserts...


}


       protected static Person createExpectedPerson(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Person expectedPerson = gson.fromJson(IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Person.class);
        return expectedPerson;
    }
```

When I run this test locally in Intelij it works as expected, but when I run it in jenkins it fails, is it due to me using the relative path? e.g:

```
/com/my/package/personStub/person1Stub.json
```

How can I ensure that the path to this file is found when running on jenkins and locally?

Comment: What build system are you using, gradle, maven or something else?

Comment: Where is the location of the json file? Is it in the same package as the Test file?

Comment: Probably use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` instead: `PersonsTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`. In addition, maybe try removing the leading `/` on the path you pass to `getResourceAsStream` (though I am not sure that one makes a difference)

Comment: @Mitch no it is not in the same package, this would cause an error, if so then why can it run and pass locally?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa build system is gradle

Comment: @java123999 Ah I didn't read that it passes locally. My bad. Are you sure you added the file to your SCM system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `person1Stub.json` is on your classpath when you run the test from your build system, does the following works:

```
Person expectedPerson = createExpectedObject(PersonsTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/my/package/personStub/person1Stub.json"));
```

Comment: ok - does it work when you load using the `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`?